# Make code execute each time an object is created when there are several constructors in a class

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a class User that I want to assign an id to on creation. I do this to do so:

```
public class User  {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

  private int id;
  private static int count;

  {
    id = count++;
  }

  public User()  {}

  public User(String firstName)  {...}

  public User(String lastName)  {...}
}
```

However I'm not sure if it's the best approach? Would a better practice be putting the `id = count++` code inside the default constructor and calling it in every other constructor like:

```
public User(String firstName)  {
  this();
  ...
}
```

class `User` also has children like `Student`, `Worker`, etc.

Comment: @user207421 What do you mean? As of now it is not repeated - the id is set only once inside the initialization block

Comment: You could simply have ` private int id = count++`; without the initialisation block

Comment: @racraman that sounds like another way that I've missed! Another user (he deleted his answer) also used that approach, so I'll probably stick with it? I think I heard that initialization blocks are worse practice than constructors/inline initialization

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just create a User Array or User Collection?